Chart.js の tooltip 表示について
Chart.jsによるグラフ表示を構築しています。基本的な実装は完了していますが、グラフエリア上にマウスHoverした時に常に表示されるtooltipを、グラフエリアの例えば上半分にHoverされた時は表示を消し、再び下半分にHoveerしたら再表示させることをしたいのですが、オプション指示方法が不明です。ご教示いただけますでしょうか。
    const chart = new Chart(id, {
        data: Data,
        .....
        options: {
            tooltips: {
                enabled: true,
                intersect: false,
                mode: 'index',
                callbacks: {
                .....


それほど詳しい訳ではないので違っていたらスミマセンが、callbacks は表示される tooltip のテキストをカスタマイズするためのオプションだと思います。
挙がっている要件からすると external を使う必要があると思います。External tooltip についてアシストが必要だったら、現在の実装（期待通りに動いていないバージョン）を JSFiddle などで見れるようにして質問すれば、より具体的な回答が付くと思います。
